# How can I move a certain entry in the bibliography to the top of the list?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, bibliography

I'm using bibliography integrated in MS Word. The bibliography list is sorted alphabetically. I use ISO 690 bibliography style.

ISO 690 requires that if you use any of your own previous papers, you need to them to be on the top of the bibliography list - the rest still needs to be sorted alphabetically.

So the question is - how can I move certain entry to the top of the list?

Any ideas? I want to use something systematic (like update XML and add checkbox "my own work") than some hacks like adding a space at the beggining.

Comment: Maybe if you can rephrase your question it would be more understandable

Comment: OK, I tried to rephrase the quesion. :)